# Вывод данных из связанных таблиц в yii2

Tags: php, yii2, gridview

В БД есть три таблицы, свзянанные внешними ключами.

```
-- `country`
   `id`
   `name`

-- `region`
   `id`
   `name`
   `country_id`

-- `city`
   `id`
   `name`
   `region_id`
```

С помощью генератора Gii сгенерировал код для таблицы `city`. 
С помощью `GridView` вывел следующие данные из полей: Название Региона, Название Города, но не могу понять как вывести название Страны.

Как вывести так что бы все названия (Страна, Регион, Город) были в одной таблице с помощью `Gridview`?

Comment: Вообще средствами gridview можно ли это реализовать

Comment: Есть у кого нибудь идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас настроены связи то можно:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    //...
    'columns' => [
        'region.country.name:text:Страна',
        'region.name:text:Регион',
        'name:text:Город',
    ],
]) ?>
```

Comment: а как для поля `Страна` добавить поля поиска в тот же `Gridview` ?

Comment: В принципе работает но к БД очень много запросов получается, можно ли это как нибудь оптимизировать ?

Comment: Почитайте про [жадную загрузку](http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2docs-ru/guide-db-active-record.html#lazy-eager-loading).

Comment: читал пока что не очень понятно